# General solution of a partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for $u(x,y)$ of the partial differential equation
$$(δu/δx)(-1/(2x))u=(1/(2x^2))\;\;(x>0).$$
I solve it but I think there is wrong.

My answer is 
$$u=-x+\sqrt \pi e^{x^2/4}+ e^{x^2/4}$$

Please help me with this question if you can.

Comment: Please use latex, your question is very difficult to read. See here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

If the question is
$$
-\frac{u}{2x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2x^2}
$$
then we have
$$
-\frac{1}{4x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u^2 =\frac{1}{2x^2}\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u^2  = -\frac{2}{x}
$$
so 
$$
u^2(x,y) = -2\ln x + g(y)
$$
or
$$
u(x,y) = \pm\sqrt{-2\ln x + g(y)} = \pm\sqrt{g(y) - \ln x^2}
$$

Comment: thank for your answer but this my equation  
(δu/δx)*(-1/2x)*u=(1/(2x^2 )                             (x>0).

Comment: Is what you wrote different to my equation? $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{2x}\right)u = \frac{-1}{2x}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Comment: yes is different